# How can I Store SQL Server Query Results into a List of String?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to store what's returned from a database query into a list of string. I've got this code:

```
List<String> slDistinctUncommonWords = new List<string>();
. . .
slDistinctUncommonWords = GetDistinctWordsFromDB();
. . .
private List<String> GetDistinctWordsFromDB()
{
    List<String> slDistinctWords = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        string sQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT UncommonWord " +
                        "FROM WORDSTATS " +
                        "ORDER BY UncommonWord"; 
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, sqlConnection);
        sqlConnection.Open();
        slDistinctWords = (List<String>)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        sqlConnection.Close();
        return slDistinctWords;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```

The "slDistinctUncommonWords = GetDistinctWordsFromDB();" line fails, though, with "*Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]'*".

Comment: ExecuteScalar only returns the first column value of the first row of the first result set. You want to use maybe ExecuteReader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [**ExecuteReader**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader?view=sqlclient-dotnet-core-1.1) instead of [**ExecuteScalar**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), like the following code:

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        slDistinctWords.Add(reader["UncommonWord"].ToString());
    }
}
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Put into a datatable

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            List<string> slDistinctWords = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.Field<string>(0)).Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

A SqlDataReader can be treated as a collection of IDataRecord objects.  So

```
var col = new List<String>();
using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
     col = rdr.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(r => r.GetString(0)).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server, try to replace your SQL query statement with this:

```
string sQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT CAST(UncommonWord AS VARCHAR(32)) + ',' " +
                "FROM WORDSTATS " +
                "ORDER BY UncommonWord FOR XML PATH('')";
```

Comment: The question is asking for a `List<string>`, not a `string`. At minimum, if you we’re inclined toward this approach, you‘d `Split()` the results by `,` and convert that to a list.

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
private List<String> GetDistinctWordsFromDB()
{
    List<String> slDistinctWords = new List<string>();
    try
    {
        string sQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT UncommonWord " +
                        "FROM WORDSTATS " +
                        "ORDER BY UncommonWord"; 
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connection);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sQuery, sqlConnection);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        sqlConnection.Open();
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            slDistinctWords.Add(reader.GetString(0));
        }
        reader.Close();
        sqlConnection.Close();
        return slDistinctWords;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}
```